# Spotfire for cross fact table joins using conformed dimensions

Tags: spotfire, star-schema

A few years I ascertained that Spotfire cannot perform multi-fact table queries using conform dimensions a la Ralph Kimball - like Tableau in which this is still the case.

Is this still so? Most people I speak to are not aware of this. I am not in a position to quickly assess this, hence my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are reading from a DB, you can create custom information links using SQL (or what Spotfire calls SQL, its a little different) that can certainly join multiple fact tables together through conforming dimensions. These may perform well or poorly depending on the amount of data and structure of the tables in question.

You can also 'join' fact tables across dimensions (or directly to each other if you have the right keys) within the tool itself. These are called relations and work under the same principles, but don't kick off joined SQL statements.

If you create a view in the DB that does the joins as you have said, Spotfire can read those as well into an information link.

Comment: Pre-joining is not a good idea. COGNOS and Bus Obj generate the SQL for you. I am looking for a definitive answer if it is possible. Tableau state NO we do not support that in reality. So? Non-joined SQL is not an issue as long as the result is correct. Thus?

Comment: In the right space pre joining is fine and can eliminate overhead as you know exactly the type of query that is coming over, and can control the SQL that gets generated. OBIEE has been using a pre joined model for decades. It generates the SQL for you based on pre joined objects behind the scenes. I guess maybe I don't understand your question. Spotfire will not create SQL for you without being told how. You can tell it how through the SQL editor in information links, or by creating relations in Spotfire (which doesn't generate SQL), or by using something like a data virtualization layer.